# Из двоичной в десятичную

Tags: python

```
def binary_array_to_number(arr):
    return int("".join(map(str, arr)), 2)
```

Эта функция преобразует двоичные числа в десятичные. Как она работает???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def binary_array_to_number(arr):
    step_1 = map(str, arr)   # элементы iterable (списка) в строки
    step_2 = "".join(step_1) # соединяем строки в 1 строку
    step_3 = int(step_2, 2)  # приводим строку к целому по основанию 2
    return step_3

l = [0, 1, 1, 0]

print(binary_array_to_number(l))
```